# Push Notifications Crashing Login and Not Appearing [Obj-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, push

My latest app needs to have a function to let the user know when s/he gets a new message via a push notification. Now, our database is being hosted by a company owned by Facebook called Parse.com. I thought that it would work if I did a query and then displayed a notification in a for loop. My code is right here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CustomMessage"];
[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:PFUser.currentUser];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        // The find succeeded.
       // NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);

        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            NSDictionary *data = @{
                                   @"alert" : @"You've got sent a new message. Open the app to read the message.",
                                   @"badge" : @"my app",
                                   };
            PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
            [push setData:data];
            [push setQuery:query];
            [push sendPushInBackground];

 }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
}
```

I'm not really sure if my code is correct and where I should place it. My app doesn't require the user to login but I decided to put this code in the viewDidLoad method of my LoginFormViewController.m, the file which stores the code for the user login system. I did this because I thought since it shows this view for a seccond or so it would be a good place to put it. But I seem to be wrong as the push notification just doesn't appear... Furthermore, I want this push notification to be able to work when the user isn't using the app and display it at the lock screen or when they are using another app, etc. Where should I put the code for this to work, and more importantly is this code correct and if not what would be the correct way to do this? Also, I'm open to using cloud code in case anybody knows how to use it.

Also, when I run the app and click the Login button the app crashes and gives this error:

```
2015-03-14 11:58:27.108 appname[14614:957253] did load ok

2015-03-14 11:58:27.223 appname[14614:957253] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.

 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

2015-03-14 11:58:27.232 appname[14614:957253] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.

 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

2015-03-14 11:58:27.842 appname[14614:957370] Error: no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.4.1)

2015-03-14 11:58:27.882 appname[14614:957253] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)

2015-03-14 11:58:27.882 appname[14614:957253] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)

2015-03-14 11:58:27.882 appname[14614:957253] Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "net.yqpc.iOS.HappyMed"

2015-03-14 11:59:15.798 appname[14614:957253] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011200df35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110d4ebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45

2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011200de6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205

3   appname                           0x000000010e1889d1 +[PFInternalUtils assertValidClassForQuery:] + 333

4   appname                           0x000000010e171d19 -[PFQuery whereKey:equalTo:] + 86

5   appname                           0x000000010e152049 -[LoginFormViewController viewDidLoad] + 185

6   UIKit                               0x000000010e59ca90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738

7   UIKit                               0x000000010e59cc8e -[UIViewController view] + 27

8   UIKit                               0x000000010e5d4d3b -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 149

9   UIKit                               0x000000010e57cec2 -[UIPresentationController preferredContentSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer:] + 101

10  UIKit                               0x000000010e57ab0d __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 108

11  UIKit                               0x000000010e49a331 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 314

12  UIKit                               0x000000010e49a1ab _afterCACommitHandler + 516

13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f42dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23

14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f42d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368

15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f38b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123

16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111f38486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470

17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111eab9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161

18  UIKit                               0x000000010e477420 UIApplicationMain + 1282

19  appname                           0x000000010e154093 main + 115

20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001155cb145 start + 1

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you want the current user to get a message via push? i.e. send a push to yourself or to a different user?

Comment: Yes, @Kex. You're correct.

Comment: You stated your app doesn't require users to log in. So are you using anonymous users?

Answer (score -1):

This line is wrong:

```
[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:PFUser.currentUser];
```

You need :  `[query whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];`

Also make sure that toUser is a NSString.

This is also wrong (the query part):

```
            [push setData:data];
            [push setQuery:query];
            [push sendPushInBackground];
```

You are using the same query as above so the username part is wrong as mentioned but also to send a push you need to be accessing the PFInstallation with something like this:

```
            PFQuery *usernameQuery = [PFUser query];
            [usernameQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:yourName];
            PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
            [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:usernameQuery];
```

then use the above pushQuery instead of yours i.e..

```
            PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
            [push setQuery:pushQuery];
            [push setData:pushData];
```

For this to work however you need to make sure the user is associated with the installation on login do this:

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

Make sure AppDelegate.m has something like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

Not sure why you wan't to send a push to yourself though, they aren't 100% reliable.

Comment: How else would I do this @Kex? Would I do that via Cloud Code? I'm also open to that since it would reduce space and I'd like to see what this Cloud Code thing is all about! Thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cloud code. Not quite clear on what you want to do. You want to send a push to yourself if there are new messages right? Or something push styled that appears as a notification even if the app is closed.

Comment: I want the user to get a message or a notification or some sort of alert to tell them they've got a new message. Like in Whatsapp.

Comment: Wouldn't is be better for the user who sends you a message to send you the push? I.e user A messages user B, so user A sends a push notification.

Comment: I'm building a messaging app and do it like that

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how you did it your way @Kex? It seems like a much better way but I have no idea how to do it:(